# How to get email diffs for GitHub pushes?

Tags: git, email, diff, github

Has anyone come up with a good way to get emails when commits are pushed to your GitHub repo -- that includes a diff of files changed?

(I know they have an Email Service Hook - but that doesn't include a diff)

Mega bonus points if the diffs are colorized with inline CSS that's viewable in Gmail.

Comment: https://github.com/jtek/git-hook-update-notify-email looks promising, but I'd appreciate any instructions on how to use it

Comment: You can't use git-hook-update-notify-email with github. It runs on your local machine.

Comment: Is their email service hook a hardcoded thing, or can you go mess with its source?

Comment: I can't mess with their email thing, though I can add a Post-Receive URL ( http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/ )

Answer (score 9):

I've written a small WebHook that exactly fills this gap: [gitdub](https://github.com/mavam/gitdub). It leverages [git-notifier](http://www.icir.org/robin/git-notifier/) to send one email per commit.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the GitHub Email Service hook doesn't include diff: this is currently a **[feature request](http://support.github.com/discussions/post-receive-issues/129-get-the-diff-of-the-commit-in-the-post-commit-email)**.

[J-16 SDIZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88442/j-16-sdiz) is also right, [`git-hook-update-notify-email`](https://github.com/jtek/git-hook-update-notify-email) would only be executed locally, not on GitHub side.

That doesn't mean said script cannot help: the idea would be to

- setup a bare repo on your side, cloning the GitHub repo
- setup a clone of that base repo
- have a cron job (or Windows task) fetching the GitHub repo every 10 minutes
- immediately push to the local non-bare repo

In the local non-bare repo, you can:

- either use a pre-receive hook (which, [as described in the Git book](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html), could be use to compute diff between `old-rev` and `new-rev`)
- or use the aforementioned `git-hook-update-notify-email`

In both cases, that mean setup this kind of service locally, which is not ideal.

Comment: What about having a server running git-hook-update-notify-email and using a Post-Receive Hook? http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/ The question is how to set up that exactly, the project isn't very well documented.

Comment: @philfreo: sure, but in both case you need to have that server on your side (which is what I mean by "locally"), not on GitHub side.

Comment: Yes I understand. Any idea how that project works / how to set it up?

Comment: @philfreo: sadly no, I have no direct experience with that kind of setup.

Comment: apparently the feature request discussion was killed.

Comment: @gcb indeed, now it would be one of the events at https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events

Answer (score 2):

May not be the ideal answer for you but if you set up [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) on your own server you can setup [git-commit-notifer](https://github.com/bitboxer/git-commit-notifier), get beautiful colored diff emails, and have unlimited git accounts since you own the server. I do this, and I have never looked back.

Don't have a server? You can get a micro Amazon EC2 instance for dirt cheap ($15 a month). We have up to 12 developers and 10 git repos and it all works great on a micro instance.

Answer (score 2):

The way of doing this is by adding a notification hook script which posts data to your system, with each commit that has been pushed to github.

E.g.: the payload consists of each commits applied, each having an id:

```
{
  :before     => before,

  :after      => after,

  :ref        => ref,

  :commits    => [{

    :id        => commit.id, <--- here
[...]
```

Second step is to make your script trigger a call to github, using github API, that fetches each commit included in the payload. The response includes a diff for each file, which then you can email to your developers.

E.g.: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha
```

:sha is the id of the commit you are getting the code for, and the response looks like this:

```
[...]

 "files": [

    {
      "filename": "file1.txt",
      "additions": 10,
      "deletions": 2,
      "changes": 12,
      "status": "modified",
      "raw_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/raw/7ca483543807a51b6079e54ac4cc392bc29ae284/file1.txt",
      "blob_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/blob/7ca483543807a51b6079e54ac4cc392bc29ae284/file1.txt",
      "patch": "@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@\n....." <---- HERE
    } 
[...]
```

Hope this helps. Please ask if you need more details about how to do it.